# Uninstalling mule from services.msc on Windows XP OS

Tags: windows-xp, uninstall

I've downloaded a version of mule and have installed it via cmd using the command "mule install" from C:\mule\bin.  Now it is in my Windows services window.  Unfortunately, I think my mule program has become corrupt and I want to uninstall this.  How can I uninstall it and make it so that it won't be a service on my machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to remove it using [SC.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sc.mspx?mfr=true) (Service Controller).

IE.: `sc delete <service_name>`

> DESCRIPTION:
>
> Deletes a service entry from the registry.
>
> If the service is running, or another process has an open handle to the service, the service is simply marked for deletion.

Or: head to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services in the registry (use RegEdit), find the entry related to the service you wish to remove, and delete it.  You may need to reboot for it to take full effect.

Comment: When using the manual method, don't forget `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\LEGACY_<servicename>`.

Comment: @grawity - don't forget what about it? sorry, this is new to me. thanks..

Comment: @O_O He's suggesting you also ensure you delte that registry key.  Try SC first, it's much less scary. :)